# How to remove energy from inductor using semiconductors?

Tags: inductor, semiconductors, polarity, coil

So I have this coil and I'm driving dc current through it. This coil has inductance and thus stores energy from the dc current.

I have to remove this energy before I can change the polarity of my h-bridge to prevent dangerous voltage rises.
How can I efficiently remove this stored energy from the coil immediately after it has been disconnected from the current source?
Would just using a bipolar capacitor in series with small resistor and paraller with the coil like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV09MW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can I just ask how much energy are we actually talking about here? because remember even 1 Joule can be a million volts, or 1 volt, and various currents/discharge time. If the entire system is only "low" power, then you can get away with standard clamp diode configurations seen in H bridge circuit designs intended for DC motor driving, as these operate the same way (coils, discharging and changing direction etc)

Comment: @KyranF We are talking about 16 volts and about ten amperes.

Comment: and what's the estimated switching time from one direction to another? Is your application low Hz or is it high Hz switching?

Comment: you may benefit from reading this, the author's reference to "flyback diodes" is the important part here, which deals with inductive loads being switched and their resulting voltage spikes. Only the first few pages are actually useful to you! http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/images/8/84/ProjectW2011.pdf

Comment: and a pretty simple diagram to show where/how the diodes are connected http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/step/circuitsf/10.gif

Comment: @KyranF It's going to be near one millisecond delay between changes in the current direction.

Comment: I'm sure with the accumulated information there can be some formula/calculations done on total energy to help you select the correct power rating diodes etc.. but i'm not skilled enough in that so just wait until one of the EE Lords gets around to helping out ;)

Comment: @Tut By changing polarity I mean switching h-bridge.

Comment: People suggesting diodes haven't considered the supply polarity reversal .. what you want is a large snubber capacitor across the coil. See http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.engsoc.org%2F~bbarnes%2Fproject%2Freference%2Fhbridge-reference-ualberta-arvp.pdf&ei=tF4tVOvgMZDjaoHugsgD&usg=AFQjCNH6D9sTzelUeRu_kS2pcF7VqhVa1A&sig2=RR4zgIsAB4jmuWFZmjcotA&bvm=bv.76477589,d.d2s

Comment: @pjc50 Please tell me more bout this snubber capacitor. Is it just unipolar capacitor connected paraller to the coil?

Comment: Bipolar capacitor in series with a small resistor. See e.g. http://homepages.which.net/~paul.hills/Emc/Snubbers.html

Comment: @pjc50 Good point about the (zener) diode solution not working with polarity reversal. If the h-bridge uses Mosfets, the body diodes would prevent using an increased voltage. If bi-polar, the max reverse-voltage specs would likely be a problem.

Comment: @Tut check my edit. What would you think about that circuit? Would it act like a resonator dissipating the energy in resistor?

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer I think you should show your h-bridge or at the very least mention it in the question. It is very relevant to finding a workable solution.

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer I could not find where you have specified the inductance (L) of the coil (it is not 1 uH as in the diagram is it?). We need to know L so we know how much energy can be in the coil. If you don't know L, could you tell us the diameter and number of turns of wire?

Comment: @MikeSweeney 2,5 mm diameter copper wire with 200 turns.

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer Oops. I should have been more clear. I meant the diameter of your coil. Also the length (if greater than 10% of diameter). Is the coil in free air or is there any ferromagnetic material near it? These details are needed to calculate the inductance and therefore the maximum coil energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just parallel the inductor with back-to-back Zeners, or a TVS, like this:[image]

Or don't do anything at all if the MOSFETs you're using have parasitic diodes which can take the current hit from the inductor when you switch.

Or, if they don't, you could do this:

[image]

Comment: Is that just a single zener or two zeners with cathode cathode connection?

Comment: Oh I see what u did there... Only realized this after taking a closer look at how zener diodes work. Very clever :D

Comment: Would the schematic editor (CircuitLab) not suffice for this example? Just wondering.

Comment: @JYelton: Yes, it would. Why? Was my intent not clear?

Comment: Not that I don't appreciate hand-drawn schematics (they are often quite nice) but I just thought it might look more professional here (since there are so few components). :)

Comment: @EMFields Yeah. Also my mosfets DO have parasitic diodes, but the backward flow of current would destroy my capacitor bank (electrolytic unipolar capacitors in parallel) where my current is coming into my h-bridge.

Comment: @The amateur programmer: I doubt that seriously since if your power supply is a voltage source it'll just - within limits - suck up the transient. What's the inductance of your inductor, its series resitance, the capacitance of your caps and their ESRs, what does your power supply look like, and how about a real schematic with reference designations and parts values?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you dissipate the energy in an inductor by allowing it to circulate it through a resistance.  In the simplest (single-ended) form, you have a 'flywheel diode', which just circulates the current through the inductor.   The dissipation occurs as Vf * I in the diode and Rl * I^2 in the inductor, where Rl is the resistance of the inductor.

The voltage of the 'bottom end' of the inductor rises to Vf above the supply rail during circulation, so doesn't impose much extra voltage stress on the rest of the circuit.

To cause the current to decay faster, you can add additional resistance in series with the flywheel diode.  This adds R * I^2 to your dissipation, but increases the overvoltage by IR volts, which is the trade-off.

Alternatively you can add a zener diode in series with the flywheel diode (but anode to anode) which allows the voltage to rise higher, and then dissipates Vz * I in the diode, while adding Vz to the over-voltage.

Pretty much you're just trading-off voltage spike height against speed of dissipation.

Comment: If I put diode paraller with the inductor would it allow current to go through the diode instead of the inductor when polarity is changed?

Comment: A couple disadvantages of the resistor (vs the zener diode) are: 1) the peak voltage varies with changes in inductor (resistance of inductor) or power supply voltage, and 2) the voltage decays as the current decays making it less effective. Item 1 can be important if switching electronically so as to avoid burning out the switching device.

Comment: We use the Zener and series diode, and then a Resistor in parallel with that and the coil.  The zener sucks up the big spike and then you get an L/R time for the rest.  You are always wasting a bit of current through the resistor.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold So u mean like having zener and "normal" diode in series and that circuit in parallel with coil and resistor?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold What about diode polarities? Anode to anode or cathode to cathode? Or cathode to anode?

Comment: Yeah, I think that is what Will Dean said.  You need the regular diode to stop the zener from conducting in the forward direction.  If this is in a circuit that goes both ways, then you'd need to pick the zener voltage to be above the maximum applied voltage.

Comment: @Will: A back-to-back Zener and conventional diode in series will only work in one direction.

Comment: @EM Fields - yes - I didn't give a good answer to the h-bridge specifics

Answer (score 1):

OK this also may work (in response to the parallel cap idea.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftXXSC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So this might work,  depending on L and R.
L is the coil inductance and R the coil resistance.
You choose C such that RC = L/R or C = L/R^2.
This then makes it a low Q resonant circuit.  (Search for Zobel network)
And it will decay with a time constant of RC = L/R.
If you have to voltage head room you can add more series R to the coil and get it to switch faster.

(Is there some way to make the schematic smaller?)

Comment: Why u put another resistor in series with the inductor? To represent the resistance of the inductor?

Comment: Yup, it's the coil resistance.  But you can also add more resistance in series to make the circuit snappier.  (at the cost of more voltage to drive it, and more power dissipation in the resistor.)

Comment: Is there a way to calculate how long does it take to dissipate the energy then?

Comment: I'm going to do this with zener diodes though just realized how to :D

Comment: @George: The brute force way: add dots on the left and right to give you the display width which will shrink the art to the  size you want.  There may be a nice way to do it with commands, but I looked and I couldn't find anything.